# Python: memmap list of objects become 'None' type inside joblib parallel

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, nonetype, joblib, numpy-memmap

I am doing the following:

1. I have a list of tensorflow DNN layers. `nn.append(tf.layers.dense(...))`
2. Each of the above list is appended to a list of np.memmap objects. `nnList[i] = nn`
3. I can access the memmap list and retrieve the tensors. But when try to access the tensors inside `joblib.parallel` it returns 'None' type object. However, the length of the memmap list is correct inside `joblib.parallel`.

I have attached a sample code below.

```
    import os
    import tempfile
    import numpy as np
    import tensorflow as tf
    from joblib import Parallel, delayed, load, dump

    tmpFolder = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    __nnFile = os.path.join(tmpFolder, 'nn.mmap')
    nnList = np.memmap(__nnFile, dtype=object, mode='w+', shape=(5))

    def main():
        for i in range(5):
            nn = []
            input = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(1, 8))
            nn.append(tf.layers.dense(inputs=input, units=8, activation=tf.sigmoid,  
                                        trainable=False))
            nn.append(tf.layers.dense(inputs=nn[0], units=2, activation=tf.sigmoid,  
                                        trainable=False))

            nnList[i] = nn

        print('nnList: ' + str(len(nnList)))
        for i in range(5):
            nn = nnList[i]
            print(nn)
            print(nn[-1])
            print('---------------------------  ' + str(i))

        with Parallel(n_jobs = -1) as parallel:
            parallel(delayed(func1)(i) for i in range(5))

    def func1(i):
        print('nnList: ' + str(len(nnList)))
        for x in range(5):
            nn = nnList[x]
            print(nn)
            print('---------------------------  ' + str(x))

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

The above code gives this output. Note the length of the arrays and how the tensors become `None`.

```
    nnList: 5
    [<tf.Tensor 'dense/Sigmoid:0' shape=(1, 8) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'dense_1/Sigmoid:0' shape=(1, 2) dtype=float32>]
    Tensor("dense_1/Sigmoid:0", shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32)
    ---------------------------  0
    [<tf.Tensor 'dense_2/Sigmoid:0' shape=(1, 8) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'dense_3/Sigmoid:0' shape=(1, 2) dtype=float32>]
    Tensor("dense_3/Sigmoid:0", shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32)
    ---------------------------  1
    [<tf.Tensor 'dense_4/Sigmoid:0' shape=(1, 8) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'dense_5/Sigmoid:0' shape=(1, 2) dtype=float32>]
    Tensor("dense_5/Sigmoid:0", shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32)
    ---------------------------  2
    [<tf.Tensor 'dense_6/Sigmoid:0' shape=(1, 8) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'dense_7/Sigmoid:0' shape=(1, 2) dtype=float32>]
    Tensor("dense_7/Sigmoid:0", shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32)
    ---------------------------  3
    [<tf.Tensor 'dense_8/Sigmoid:0' shape=(1, 8) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'dense_9/Sigmoid:0' shape=(1, 2) dtype=float32>]
    Tensor("dense_9/Sigmoid:0", shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32)
    ---------------------------  4
    nnList: 5
    None
    ---------------------------  0
    None
    ---------------------------  1
    None
    ---------------------------  2
    None
    ---------------------------  3
    None
    ---------------------------  4
```

How can I access the tensors inside `joblib.parallel`? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue back then. Hope it helps someone in the future.

The `None` problem had nothing to do with the tensors. I was using the `joblib.Parallel` function the wrong way.

One should pass the variable to `delayed` to be accessible to the forked processes (how did I overlook that in the documentation!). The correct way:

```
with Parallel(n_jobs = -1) as parallel:
    parallel(delayed(func1)(i, WHATEVER_VARIABLE_I_WANT) for i in range(5))
```